# application logs show 500 error from call Mulesoft web service

Tags: mule, esb, mulesoft

we have a application that makes a web service call to Mule ESB and the log shows mostly 500 error code during peak hours and 200 success code during off peak hours. I am not part of the Mule team, but when I talked with them they indicate that this may not be a problem on their side, they are saying nothing is received on their ends.
Now my question is if our application logs show 500 error code, won't that indicate the request has made it to the Mule ESB but was not able to process it or still possible to get 500 error code if the request is lost somewhere due to networking / router issues or similar to that?

Answer (score 1):

The question is totally generic and doesn't provide any insight on the implementation. Then his answer applies to any HTTP response from any implementation and technology, be it Mule, Java Python, etc.

The answer depends on if the server is using the 500 response correctly. If they just answer 500 because it doesn't handle errors correctly then there is nothing you can imply from that.

If 500 is used correctly it is an internal error. If the issue is that they don't receive a proper response from another backend it be argued if there is not a better response code for that like 502 or 504. In any case is that team that manages the app who should troubleshoot the error.

What you can buy sure is that the request reached the application because it responded with an HTTP response.